# How to make SVN touch local files and assign them their last commit date?

Tags: svn

I used the `use-commit-times=yes` setting on SVN config so it defaults updated files date to that of the last commit. It works. But only for files that have to be updated. Remaining files keep their current date.

I need the whole working copy to have the last commit date for any unmodified files.

My current solution is ungainly, at best: remove all the files of each repo and either update or clean-up them. Both work, but take eons.

Any suggestion?